# Can I plant my amaryllis outside?

Tags: houseplants, flowers, plant-care, bulbs, amaryllis

I live in Bromley (southern England) and was given a gorgeous amaryllis a few years ago. It is a Hippeastrum Monte Carlo.

Unfortunately my wife seems to be allergic to the pollen but loves the flowers. Last year I tried to trim off the stamen which helped, but not enough.

We have a semi-sheltered, semi-shaded balcony. I was wondering if it is viable to place outside whilst in flower? It has just started sending up its first flower this week, so I expect it to open soon (mid April).

Comment: When's your typical last frost date? Amaryllis is not fond of the cold.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - the last week of April is apparently our last frost date, but as far as I am aware we haven't had anything below 3c for the last couple of months.

Answer (score 3):

The last week of May is the last frost date in the UK, Avierose, but its just a guide - we've had frost on 4th June before, and I was living in your borough the last time that happened. Unfortunately, by end of May, it will probably not be flowering. They're not hardy outdoors here in the UK, and although the bulb benefits from being placed outdoors for a while in June and July, actually having them as a flowering plant outdoors is difficult. If your balcony was southfacing and in full sun, well sheltered from winds, I might have suggested you try hardening it off and see what happens, but I suspect what would happen is the flowers and foliage would shrivel.

More info here  https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=118

I do have a suggestion though; since the problem is because of pollen sensitivity, why not grow one of the double forms of Hippeastrum? Like other double flowered forms of plants, they have no pollen or stamens at all, especially the red or red and white bi colour ones (see Exotic Peacock as a variety, picture here http://cactus-spb.narod.ru/4.12.html), though some double forms of Hippeastrum do produce pollen at the edge of a normal petal instead, varies according to variety. White double versions often have petaloid stamens, often with pollen though.